# Search column via Binary search based on another clustered column - SQL Server Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

Say, I have an append-only audit table with following schema:

```
ColumnX, AuditRowId, AuditDTim
CLUSTERED INDEX ON AuditRowId
```

How do I write a 'performant' SQL Server query to find `COUNT(*)` of rows between specific `AuditDTim` values?

These are the restrictions:

- I want to use SQL. No migration of data to BigData platforms.
- We cannot change clustered index to `AuditDTim`. Assume legacyDb and no DDL access.
- We cannot add new index to `AuditDTim`.
- Assume it's a very big table with billions of records
- Relation between AuditRowId and AuditDTim - both are incremental in nature, ie, as AuditRowId increases, AuditDTim either increases or remains the same.

Comment: Is AuditDTim correlated with AuditRowId in any way?

Comment: @Martin, Yes, both are sequential and incremental in nature. For e.g., as AuditRowId increases, AuditDTim will either be the same or increase.

Comment: @lad20125, No table partitioning either - assume this is a legacy table with no DDL access.

Comment: So yes you should be able to use two binary searches on AuditRowId to find the ID associated with the start time and the end time and then do a range seek between those two Id.

Comment: @Martin, yep, that's what I thought. Any query/ function in handy?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use two binary searches on AuditRowId.

One to find the ID associated with the start time and another to find the ID associated with the end time and then do a range seek between those two Id.

An example of the basic idea is below: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0270c/2) (though I'm not guaranteeing it is bug free)

```
DECLARE @AuditDTimStart DATETIME = '2000-01-15',
        @AuditDTimEnd   DATETIME = '2000-01-20'

IF @AuditDTimEnd < @AuditDTimStart
  RAISERROR('Start date after end date',16,1)

DECLARE @AuditRowIdStart INT,
        @AuditRowIdEnd   INT,
        @AuditRowIdMin1  INT,
        @AuditRowIdMax1  INT,
        @AuditRowIdMin2  INT,
        @AuditRowIdMax2  INT

SELECT TOP 1 @AuditRowIdMin1 = AuditRowId,
             @AuditRowIdMin2 = AuditRowId,
             @AuditRowIdStart = -1 + CASE
                                       WHEN @AuditDTimStart < AuditDTim
                                         THEN AuditRowId
                                     END
FROM   YourTable
ORDER  BY AuditRowId

SELECT TOP 1 @AuditRowIdMax1 = AuditRowId,
             @AuditRowIdMax2 = AuditRowId,
             @AuditRowIdEnd = 1 + CASE
                                    WHEN @AuditDTimEnd > AuditDTim
                                      THEN AuditRowId
                                  END
FROM   YourTable
ORDER  BY AuditRowId DESC

WHILE @AuditRowIdStart IS NULL
  BEGIN
      -- Binary search to find latest row where AuditDTim < @AuditDTimStart
      SELECT TOP 1 @AuditRowIdMax1 = CASE
                                       WHEN AuditDTim >= @AuditDTimStart
                                         THEN AuditRowId
                                       ELSE @AuditRowIdMax1
                                     END,
                   @AuditRowIdMin1 = CASE
                                       WHEN AuditDTim < @AuditDTimStart
                                         THEN AuditRowId
                                       ELSE @AuditRowIdMin1
                                     END
      FROM   YourTable
      WHERE  AuditRowId <= @AuditRowIdMin1 + ( ( @AuditRowIdMax1 - @AuditRowIdMin1 ) / 2 )
      ORDER  BY AuditRowId DESC

      IF @AuditRowIdMax1 - @AuditRowIdMin1 <= 1
        SET @AuditRowIdStart = @AuditRowIdMin1;
  END

WHILE @AuditRowIdEnd IS NULL
  BEGIN
      -- Binary search to find earliest row where AuditDTim > @AuditRowIdEnd
      SELECT TOP 1 @AuditRowIdMax2 = CASE
                                       WHEN AuditDTim > @AuditDTimEnd
                                         THEN AuditRowId
                                       ELSE @AuditRowIdMax2
                                     END,
                   @AuditRowIdMin2 = CASE
                                       WHEN AuditDTim <= @AuditDTimEnd
                                         THEN AuditRowId
                                       ELSE @AuditRowIdMin2
                                     END
      FROM   YourTable
      WHERE  AuditRowId >= @AuditRowIdMin2 + ( ( @AuditRowIdMax2 - @AuditRowIdMin2 ) / 2 )
      ORDER  BY AuditRowId ASC

      IF @AuditRowIdMax2 - @AuditRowIdMin2 <= 1
        SET @AuditRowIdEnd = @AuditRowIdMax2;
  END

SELECT *
FROM   YourTable
WHERE  AuditRowId > @AuditRowIdStart
       AND AuditRowId < @AuditRowIdEnd
ORDER  BY AuditRowId
```

Answer (score 1):

Presumably, you would use a query like this:

```
select count(*)
from audi
where auditdtim >= @auditstart and auditdtim <= @auditend;
```

The presence of indexes mostly affects the performance of the query, not how it is written.

Comment: I have few limitations which I mentioned before...
- there is no index on AuditDTim. If there are a billion records, this would take a huge time.
- I cannot add new index on this table, due to a limitation I have.
- I can only use AuditRowId

Comment: @Abin . . . Based on your limitations, there is not much you can do to improve the query.  Partitioning might help, but if you can't add an index, then you probably can't add partitions.  Triggers with a summary table might help, but if you can't add an index, you probably can't add triggers.

Answer (score 1):

Following up on Martin's answer. Tried using cte expression. Posted @ http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0270c/9/0.

Code:

```
--declare @SearchTerm datetime = '2000-01-11 00:00:00';
; with cte as
(
  select TOP 1
      Iter=convert(int,0),
      CurDTim=convert(datetime, null),
      CurId=convert(int, -1),
      CurMinId=convert(int,-1),
      CurMaxId=convert(int,-1),
      NextMinId=MIN([AuditRowId]),
      NextMaxId=MAX([AuditRowId])
    from [YourTable] (nolock) --assume clustered index only on AuditRowId
  UNION ALL
  select
      Iter=Iter+1,
      CurDTim=NextDTim,
      CurId=(((NextMaxId+NextMinId)/2)+1),
      CurMinId=NextMinId,
      CurMaxId=NextMaxId,
      NextMinId=case when NextDTim<(/*@SearchTerm*/ '2000-01-11 00:00:00' /*@SearchTerm*/) then (((NextMaxId+NextMinId)/2)+1) else NextMinId end,
      NextMaxId=case when NextDTim>(/*@SearchTerm*/ '2000-01-11 00:00:00' /*@SearchTerm*/) then (((NextMaxId+NextMinId)/2)+1) else NextMaxId end
    from cte t1
    inner join (select AuditRowId, NextDTim=AuditDTim from [YourTable] (nolock)) as t2
      on [AuditRowId] = (((NextMaxId+NextMinId)/2)+1)
    where 
      NextMinId < NextMaxId
      and (((NextMaxId+NextMinId)/2)+1) > NextMinId
      and (((NextMaxId+NextMinId)/2)+1) < NextMaxId
      and (CurDTim <> (/*@SearchTerm*/ '2000-01-11 00:00:00' /*@SearchTerm*/) or CurDTim is null)
)
select TOP 100 t1.*
from cte t1
order by t1.Iter
;
```